# JavaScript - Uncaught TypeError: totype[totypeIndex] is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, undefined

I was following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4VE_6v9hFs) & completed the tutorial & made the project but after sometime my JS shows a error `Uncaught TypeError: totype[totypeIndex] is undefined` when i tried to log the type of `totype[totypeIndex]` firstly it showed `String` and then after some time it showed `undefined`.

My Code:

```js
const typedSpan = document.querySelector(".typed") // Storing the Span of HTML of Class 'typed' for changing the text
const totype = ["Fun", "Hard", "Love"] // Array in which all of the words which have to be typed are stored

const delayTyping_char = 200; // 200ms will be waited before next Character of the Text is typed
const delayErasing_text = 150; // 100ms will be waited before removing the next character
const delayTyping_text = 3000; // 2500ms will be waited before everything is erased & next text is typed

let totypeIndex = 0; // Index of The text which is being typed
let charIndex = 0; // Index of The Character which is being typed


function typeText() {
  if (charIndex < totype[totypeIndex].length) {
    typedSpan.textContent += totype[totypeIndex].charAt(charIndex); // Value of The Span in HTML is = the Character at the index of charIndex of the Text which is being typed
    charIndex++; // Adding 1 to charIndex
    setTimeout(typeText, delayTyping_char); // Calling typeText Until the charIndex is greater than the lenght of the Text which is being typed
  } else {
    setTimeout(eraseText, delayTyping_text); // if charIndex is Greater than lenght of the text which is being type then after the time setted (delayTyping_text) erase function will be called
  }
}

function eraseText() {
  if (charIndex > 0) {
    typedSpan.textContent = totype[totypeIndex].substring(0, charIndex - 1); // substring(0, charIndex-1) here charIndex-1 is saying to select the text leaving one of last text behind
    charIndex = charIndex - 1; // subtracting 1 from charIndex
    setTimeout(eraseText, delayErasing_text); // Will call eraseText() Function until the charIndex is not equal to 0
  } else {
    totypeIndex++; // If everything is erased then the totypeIndex will be increased and next text in Array (totype) will be typed

    if (totypeIndex > totype.length) // If totypeIndex is equal to or greater than the number of text to be typed then
      totypeIndex = 0; // totypeIndex will be 0 so that we can start from the first text in the array (toType) and
    setTimeout(typeText, delayTyping_text); // after some delay presetted (delayTyping_text) typeText() Function is called
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(typeText, delayTyping_text);
} // typText() Function is called when everything is loaded
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #111111;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.effect-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.typed {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #00bdff;
}

.cursor {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #b0ff95;
  animation: blinker 800ms infinite;
}

.cursor.typing-true {
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    background-color: #b0ff95;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #b0ff95;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Wrapper Start -->
  <h1 class="effect-wrapper">Coding is <span class="typed"></span> <span class="cursor">&nbsp;</span></h1>
</div>
<!-- Wrapper End -->
```

Please Tell me what was the error & how do i fix it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Debug..... `console.log(totypeIndex, totype[totypeIndex])`

Comment: Inside the `eraseText` function, change `totypeIndex > totype.length` to `totypeIndex >= totype.length`. Value of `totypeIndex` should be reset to zero when its value is greater or _equal_ to the length of the `totype` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typo is here

```
if (totypeIndex > totype.length) // If totypeIndex is equal to or greater than the number of text to be typed then
```

you have to set this statement to be higher or equal so use `>=` instead of `>`

```js
const typedSpan = document.querySelector(".typed") // Storing the Span of HTML of Class 'typed' for changing the text
const totype = ["Fun", "Hard", "Love"] // Array in which all of the words which have to be typed are stored

const delayTyping_char = 200; // 200ms will be waited before next Character of the Text is typed
const delayErasing_text = 150; // 100ms will be waited before removing the next character
const delayTyping_text = 3000; // 2500ms will be waited before everything is erased & next text is typed

let totypeIndex = 0; // Index of The text which is being typed
let charIndex = 0; // Index of The Character which is being typed


function typeText() {
  if (charIndex < totype[totypeIndex].length) {
    typedSpan.textContent += totype[totypeIndex].charAt(charIndex); // Value of The Span in HTML is = the Character at the index of charIndex of the Text which is being typed
    charIndex++; // Adding 1 to charIndex
    setTimeout(typeText, delayTyping_char); // Calling typeText Until the charIndex is greater than the lenght of the Text which is being typed
  } else {
    setTimeout(eraseText, delayTyping_text); // if charIndex is Greater than lenght of the text which is being type then after the time setted (delayTyping_text) erase function will be called
  }
}

function eraseText() {
  if (charIndex > 0) {
    typedSpan.textContent = totype[totypeIndex].substring(0, charIndex - 1); // substring(0, charIndex-1) here charIndex-1 is saying to select the text leaving one of last text behind
    charIndex = charIndex - 1; // subtracting 1 from charIndex
    setTimeout(eraseText, delayErasing_text); // Will call eraseText() Function until the charIndex is not equal to 0
  } else {
    totypeIndex++; // If everything is erased then the totypeIndex will be increased and next text in Array (totype) will be typed

    if (totypeIndex >= totype.length) // If totypeIndex is equal to or greater than the number of text to be typed then
      totypeIndex = 0; // totypeIndex will be 0 so that we can start from the first text in the array (toType) and
    setTimeout(typeText, delayTyping_text); // after some delay presetted (delayTyping_text) typeText() Function is called
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(typeText, delayTyping_text);
} // typText() Function is called when everything is loaded
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #111111;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.effect-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.typed {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #00bdff;
}

.cursor {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #b0ff95;
  animation: blinker 800ms infinite;
}

.cursor.typing-true {
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    background-color: #b0ff95;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #b0ff95;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Wrapper Start -->
  <h1 class="effect-wrapper">Coding is <span class="typed"></span> <span class="cursor">&nbsp;</span></h1>
</div>
<!-- Wrapper End -->
```

Comment: cuz this statement is setting the totypeindex to 0 if it is higher than the totype lenght, as long as your totypeindex will not go higher than the array items then it wont loop back as per the statement, so in this case the totypeindex will stop at the last item of your array, so the text erase function wont find anymore text to erase in the loop that's why